# How to play parallel melody Pattern's in jFugue?

Tags: java, jfugue

I'm learning JFugue but I couldn't find in the documentation how can I play two or more melody lines at the same time, you know, like in a band when the line bass plays in parallel with the drums, guitars and keyboards.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by using two different channels, or voices. JFugue has the V command for this:

`player.play("V1 I[Piano] C D E V2 I[Flute] D F A");` plays two lines in melody.

You can have 16 voices (numbered 0 through 15). Note that V9 is special - it is a percussion track, and each note corresponds to a specific percussion instrument (e.g., In V9, "C5" will sound like a high bongo).